# How to create a ISO file from a bootloader on windows 10 64bit

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, 64-bit, bootloader

I want to write a simple OS from scratch. I found a [tutorial](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev1.html) that i want to use. One of the requirements for a setup is VFD, but VFD does not work on 64bit systems. So im now trying to find supstitutions. My one thought was to maybe try to make the code and stuff into an iso file and mount it in virtualBox, but i dont know how to make an iso file.

How do i create an iso file from sourcecode or is there a way to get VFD or equivalent wokring on 64bit windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. DD for windows and imdisk.

```
dd if=bootloader.bin of=bootloader.flp
imdisk -a -m A: -f bootloader.flp -s 1440K
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a binary file using nasm and load it as a floppy device from virtual box.
Alternatively, you can load the binary image from qemu...(at least on Linux)

I'm not an expert, but I think it should work.